# Convert string which contains escape characters to a dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary, escaping

I need to convert a python string which represents a dict into a python dict. The string might contain any valid dict representation, including windows style pathes (with backslashes), eg

```
mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}'
```

I would need a generic str to dict convert function, so this is just an example of a source string, which doesn't work. The source string might come from external sources. A python 2/3 compatible solution would be preferred.

I already tried the given answers:

json.loads does not work (even if I reformat the string to json syntax): raises exception

ast.literal_eval does not work: in this example it places a tab character in the result

eval: the same result as ast.literal_eval

Comment: how was this string derived? seems that whatever made it did not use proper conventions/methods

Comment: There **is** a *TAB* character in the string: ***\t*** (from *"c:\tmp....*).

Comment: There is NO tab 
"c:\tmp\.."  would have a tab
"c:\\tmp\\..." is just a backslash

Answer (score 2):

I would put a hack on the string to replace 'c:' as a raw string literal r'c:'

```
mystring = u'{"baselocaldir": "c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}'.replace('"c:', 'r"c:') 
_dict = eval(mystring)
_dict
```

Result:

```
{'baselocaldir': 'c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager'}
```

Comment: does not work, as the input string is mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}' and not mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\tmp\SrcTmp\RepManager"}' –

And: it would require t o replace all other special characters as \n \a ....

Comment: i edited my answer. Basically, you can convert the value string as raw literal so that it will ignore special chars such as \t, \n \a and others.

Comment: Edit: is not a solution, this would damage (escape)  the unicode parts of the string

Answer (score 1):

Edit3: after op change the sample string to double backslash, it is easier and no need to use regex:

```
mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}'
test = repr(mystring)[1:-1] 
print(test)

# convert to dictionary
my_dict = json.loads(test)
print('dict key "baselocaldir" = ', my_dict["baselocaldir"])
```

output:

```
{"baselocaldir":"c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}
dict key "baselocaldir" =  c:\tmp\SrcTmp\RepManager
```

Edit2: apparently using repr() alone is not enough, that's why i edited my answer to use regex and replace all the `\` to `\\`, here is the code:

```
import re, json
mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\tmp\SrcTmp\RepManager"}'

test = re.sub(r'(?<=[^\\])\\(?=[^\\])', r'\\\\', repr(mystring)[1:-1])
print(test)

# convert to dictionary
my_dict = json.loads(test)
print('dict key "baselocaldir" = ', my_dict["baselocaldir"])
```

output:

```
{"baselocaldir":"c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}
dict key "baselocaldir" =  c:\tmp\SrcTmp\RepManager
```

previous answer, which is not enough
Edit:
simple way to convert a string to raw is to use `repr()` or `"%r"`

Here is a one step solution, credits goes to [Nishanth Amuluru and 
Jed Alexander](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211-convert-a-string-into-a-raw-string/#c3) 9 years ago:

```
mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\tmp\SrcTmp\RepManager"}'

raw_str = "%r"%mystring
rep_str= repr(mystring)

print('original string = ', mystring)
print('Raw string = ', raw_str)
print('rep string = ', rep_str)
```

output:

```
original string =  {"baselocaldir":"c:  mp\SrcTmp\RepManager"}
Raw string =  '{"baselocaldir":"c:\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}'
rep string =  '{"baselocaldir":"c:\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}'
```

Comment: Both answers do not work, as the input string is

mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}'

and not 

mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\tmp\SrcTmp\RepManager"}'

Comment: @CarstenThielepape, with your new string it is easier and we can skip using regex, check my edited answer on top, it works on python 3.6

Comment: You are right, it works on python 3.x, but fails on python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

My (maybe not most elegant) solution:

But it works on python2 , python3 and with unicode chars in unicode strings:

```
text_type = None
if PY2:
    string_types = basestring
    text_type = unicode
else:
    string_types = text_type = str

def DictUnescaceBackslash(oDict):
    for key, value in iteritems(oDict):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            DictUnescaceBackslash(value)
        elif isinstance(value, string_types):
            oDict[key]=oDict[key].replace("***BaCkSlAsH***","\\")
        elif isinstance(value, list):
           for elem in value:
                DictUnescaceBackslash(elem)

mystring = u'{"baselocaldir":"c:\\tmp\\SrcTmp\\RepManager"}'
uString2 = mystring.replace("\\","***BaCkSlAsH***")
dDict    = ast.literal_eval(uString2)
DictUnescaceBackslash(dDict)
```